# Book trilogy(?) about advanced civilisation, wormholes and portals, first mission to Mars

Tags: story-identification, books, mars, wormhole

I'm trying to remember a good book, maybe divided by three volumes, about a future human society.

I remember that it starts with the first human mission to Mars, where the astronauts land just to discover two guys in their 20-ish just built some kind of portal and managed to get on Mars from their garage.

I know that after this there is a huge universe, and a lot of things going on, including a character buying and living in its own asteroid, later used to help a endangered species?

I believe later in the story we follow the two portal builders, one became incredibly rich as the CEO of the company selling portals, while the other decided to step down from it.

Later in the story, in the second book maybe, the second guy decides to explore a planet with hiking trails that are supposed to make people disappear, and he ends up traveling through several planets, one very cold and covered in snow.

I read that book about 4 years ago I think, but it was not new. I'd say it could be from the late 2000's.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189048/help-finding-a-book-title-college-students-find-a-way-to-open-portals-to-other/189050#189050

Comment: Yup, that's it, thank you !. Sorry for not researching the site enough

Comment: No problem; I think perhaps the problem is that I've spent rather too long on this site...

Comment: See also most common duplicate target at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18129/book-id-astronauts-and-lab-students-can-create-portals-through-space